# Does MapleStory work on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: wine, games

Does [MapleStory](http://maplestory.nexon.net/) work on Linux/Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like some versions of [MapleStory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maplestory) can be run with [Wine](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Wine), with some substantial success, but that there is also a long and extensive history of failure. If you already have a copy of MapleStory, you should try it and see. See [this page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=2341) and [this page](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=22287) in the Wine application database.

It also looks like people got MapleStory running in an emulated or virtualized environment [years ago](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=372928). (You may want to take that guide with a grain of salt, as it's rather old and may not apply fully now.) So you might try that, if you have a copy of Windows to install on a virtual machine (or already set up).